# List Google+ activities by collection

Tags: python, google-plus

Recently Google+ enabled the "[Collections](https://plus.google.com/collections/welcome)" feature.

Is there a way to list activities by collection name?

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list#collection) there is reference to collection but only public is allowed.

> The collection of activities to list.
>
> Acceptable values are: "public": All public activities created by the
>   specified user.

Does that refer to the new feature  or do i misinterpet?

Does anybody have more info on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Maybe Google might know :) No pun intended!

Comment: Haha no I meant maybe someone from Google might know a thing or two about new Google+ features :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature isn't available in the API yet.
I've opened a feature request here (but I wouldn't hold my breath): https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1138

The `collection` parameter has been there since the beginning, so that's nothing new (and I never quite understood why it is there when it only accepts one possible value). It would be perfect though if we could use the ID of a collection instead of `public`

Comment: The collection value is there to allow for potential future changes without breaking everyone's implementations.

Comment: @abraham let's hope that the potential future changes finally get done. So far the Google+ API seems a bit 'naked' compared to other ones.